# Get error when upgrading to laravel 7.0 From laravel 6.x

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-upgrade

I am trying to upgrade my application to laravel 7. But I got error when i entered `composer update`. And changed composer.json file as well as laravel upgrade document.

And error is :

> The "http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-2019-10%24543d5b0a9102507acbcfcd5499f758ebe96c4f5516cb7ccf042c12126ac86899.json" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable)http://repo.packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date

Why error occurred?

Comment: It looks like packagist was not working when attempting to download a file - did you try again a little bit after this error happened?

Comment: Yes. I tried two times within 10m gap but same error.

Answer (score 4):

Run this command

```
composer config -g repo.packagist composer https://packagist.org
```

Then try

```
composer udpate
```